# Cannot get javascript weather api app to display weather

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
  /* add a input box to enter city name
   apply a submit button on the page
   when user inputs city make sure a function calls openweather app
   when city is entered display results should include
   city name, current temp, weather description, min temp,max temp.
   once city is picked results should display but also change when adding an
   if statment to check if the weather is either above 85 degree or below 40 */

    $(function () {

      $('#search').submit((event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
      //console.log('form being submitted')

      })

        function displayCity(weather) {
          console.log(weather)
          // note added async to function
            function searchCity(search)

                const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,CA&appid=f674d7dcd4f4a4860d1b6eede3761c6c'     
            // make API request using #.ajax()
               $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 type: 'GET',
                 data: { q: searchTerm }

               })
               .done((response) => {
                 console.log(response)
                 // get response from successful API call and
                 // pass response data to the updateUi() function
                 displayResults(response)
               })
               .fail((error) => {
                 console.log(error)
                 alert('an error occurred')
               })
             }

             function chooseCity(city) {
              const cityName = city.name
              const cityTemp = city.main.temp
              const cityDescription = city.weather.description
              const cityTempMin = city.temp_min
              const cityTempMax = city.temp_max

              //adding jquery to update the UI
                  $('.city').text(cityName)
                  $('.temp').text(cityTemp)
                  $('.description').text(cityDescription)
                  $('.tempMin').text(cityTempMin)
                  $('.tempMax').text(cityTempMax)
                 }

              })
```

I've been writing javascript for almost 2 months, it hasn't been easy to understand as I only have brief knowledge of HTML and CSS.
I've been deleting and adding code but can't seem to figure out how to get my API working to display the weather when a user selects a city.

Comment: *"SyntaxError: missing { before function body"*

Comment: `function searchCity(search) ` **`{`** <== you missed one of those ... and there'll be a missing **`}`** as well - get to know the browser developer tools console - if you run the code snippet here you'll even see the error!

Comment: You're also not calling `displayCity` or `searchCity`. Also, `searchTerm` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in your code base.

1. `{` is missing before `searchCity`
2. `displayCity` and `searchCity` aren't called. They just declared.
3. You have used `displayResults` instead of `chooseCity`
4. `searchTerm` is not defined. it should be `search`

```js
/* add a input box to enter city name
   apply a submit button on the page
   when user inputs city make sure a function calls openweather app
   when city is entered display results should include
   city name, current temp, weather description, min temp,max temp.
   once city is picked results should display but also change when adding an
   if statment to check if the weather is either above 85 degree or below 40 */

    $(function () {

      $('#search').click((event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        displayCity(event.target.value);
      })

        function displayCity(weather) {
          searchCity(weather);
          // note added async to function
            function searchCity(search) {
              const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,CA&appid=f674d7dcd4f4a4860d1b6eede3761c6c'     
              // make API request using #.ajax()
                 $.ajax({
                   url: url,
                   type: 'GET',
                   data: { q: search }

                 })
                 .done((response) => {
                   console.log(response)
                   // get response from successful API call and
                   // pass response data to the updateUi() function
                   chooseCity(response)
                 })
                 .fail((error) => {
                   console.log(error)
                   alert('an error occurred')
                 })
               }

                

             function chooseCity(city) {
              const cityName = city.name
              const cityTemp = city.main.temp
              const cityDescription = city.weather.description
              const cityTempMin = city.temp_min
              const cityTempMax = city.temp_max

              //adding jquery to update the UI
                  $('.city').text(cityName)
                  $('.temp').text(cityTemp)
                  $('.description').text(cityDescription)
                  $('.tempMin').text(cityTempMin)
                  $('.tempMax').text(cityTempMax)
                 }

              }
              });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" name="search" type="button" value="Click me!"/>
```

Comment: Thank you all!! I still can't seem to figure out how to make it show on the screen. Javascript is really tough, can't seem to figure it out but I will continue to try..

Comment: you can give me a brief how do you want to show it on the screen. I may help you on that.